# Getting a simple thing to work in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

Anyone have any ideas why I can't get this ui.multiselect box to display properly in a backend Wordpress plugin page?

You can see the demo here....

http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

Seems pretty straightforward. But I have registered, enque'd, and just about everything I know how to do to make something work under wordpress, but all I see is.... (drumroll) ... A SELECT BOX! And it's not too pretty.

Would love to know what I'm overlooking!

Ideas Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your CSS file linked back in the backend? It's possible that you have added it on the frontend only. Or other chance is that there is another style in the backend that overrides this one after it is applied.